# How to load an unrelated Hibernate entity into another entity

Tags: java, hibernate

I am facing this little problem with Hibernate:

Suppose I have a singleton entity, let's call it Settings, which contains a user supplied value for all entities of type B that must be applied to field xyz when B is loaded.

Class B comes from an old AS/400 legacy system and adding any column to it is out of question. Actually B will always be read-only from my application. Also class B is part of a rather complex object structure coming from this legacy system and I'd like to avoid assembling this specific bit manually whenever entity B gets loaded.

Is there any way I could have Settings be loaded automatically into class B, remember that B and Settings will not share any common values in order to relate them togheter.

```
@Entity
class Settings {

    @Column 
    int some_value_to_add_to_field_xyz_in_entity_B_all_the_time;
}

@Entity
class B {

    @ManyToOne
    Settings settings;//I want this to be loaded automatically

    @Column int xyz;

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked into @postconstruct?

Comment: @efekctive From my understanding and what I tried which did not work (could be an error from my side though), Postconstruct will only work for container-managed beans, which Hibernate entities are not. I managed to acheive this by implementing onLoad of a Hibernate interceptor which loads the Settings entity when entities of type B are loaded. Not sure if it the most effective way to do it but it works.

Comment: That was my suspicion but trying the easy ones never takes much time

Comment: I was going to suggest to use the postscontruct on the consumer of the entity b to set the value (In the case the entity was injected) but your approach seems more on target